# Average of last X orders

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find the average amount of the last X orders, per customer. My data is structured as such:

- Customer ID
- Total Amount
- Date

I tried partitionning by Customer ID, then Ordering by date, but I can't find the average of the TOP X.

Comment: Please post some sample data and expected output.

Comment: one way is to calculate a row_number() partitioned by customer and ordered by Date DESC - then use that query as an inner query and select row_number <= X and take averages - or you can set it up in a WITH statement

Comment: your question is not clear,please look here to improve question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is a cte and Row_Number().  The following will give you the average order by customer.

```
Declare @YourTable table (CustID int,OrderDate Date,OrderAmount int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'2016-01-18',2500),
(1,'2016-02-13',5000),
(1,'2016-03-31',3000),
(2,'2016-03-18',1800),
(2,'2016-04-13',2200),
(2,'2016-05-31',2500)

;with cteBase as (
    Select *
          ,RowNr=Row_Number() over (Partition By CustID Order By OrderDate Desc) 
    From @YourTable
)
Select CustID
      ,AvgOrder = avg(OrderAmount)
 From cteBase
 Where RowNr<=2
 Group By CustID
```

Returns

```
CustID  AvgOrder
1       4000
2       2350
```

Comment: @user107242  Good to know.   Honestly, get comfortable with the window functions... they are invaluable.   cheers

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` window function

```
select [Customer ID],Avg([Total Amount]) as avg_amt
(
select row_number()over(partition by [Customer ID] order by [Date] desc) rn, *
from yourtable
) A
Where Rn <= 5 --change it based on requirement 
Group by [Customer ID]
```

Looks like current table is transaction table, so you may have a separate table called `Customer` where `[Customer ID]` is unique then you can use this approach also

```
SELECT c.[Customer ID],
       Avg([Total Amount])
FROM   customers c
       CROSS apply (SELECT TOP 5 [Total Amount]
                    FROM   yourtable y
                    WHERE  c.[Customer ID] = y.[Customer ID]
                    ORDER  BY [Date] DESC) cs
GROUP  BY [Customer ID]
```

The above query can be altered with `OUTER APPLY` to get list of all `customers` even though he did not make any transaction with the avg `Total Amount` zero.

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `row_number()`:

```
select customerid, avg(totalamount)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customerid order by date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= x;
```